# google chart series label

Tags: charts, label

I am setting up a bar chart using google chart, and I would like to display a value next to the bar chart to indicate the value the bar is referring to.

I know that when you hover over the bar, it will display the number as the example below:
https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#bar_chart

But I want it to display without hovering, like how you can set up a bar chart with series displaying in PowerPoint.

I am not sure if there is a way to get around this? Or is this simple a non-existence at the moment for google chart?

Thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they added this in September 2012.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content

Comment: Unfortunately they didn't add static non-mouseover tooltip labels, they just increased the customization for existing tooltips by allowing you to use HTML code to customize them.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is highly sought after, but unfortunately still not supported by Google Charts.

After long striving with this, I've made a hack to the `ComboChart` (could work with `BarChart` and `ColumnChart` as well, with a couple of changes) to insert the labels into the SVG.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/augustomen/FE2nh/

Tested on Firefox 21, Chrome 27 and IE 9.